# Calling map on NSMutableData in swift

Tags: swift

I'm having some strange behavior with NSMutableData that I can't explain.  I have a method that converts a string to a null-terminated UTF-8 array of bytes.  However, if I then use "data.map(...)" to print it out, the first byte is right and the rest look like random memory.  What's weird is if I make a copy with "let copy = data.copy() as! Data" and then use "copy.map(...)" it works just fine.  I'm converting to NSMutableData instead of Data because that's the format the API I'm using this takes it in.

Here's code to convert a string to a UTF-8 bytes array in an NSMutableData:

```
public func getUtf8Bytes(of str: String) -> NSMutableData {
    // Convert to a null-terminated UTF-8 NSMutableData
    let utf8CStringInts: [UInt8] = str.utf8CString.map { UInt8($0) }
    let count = utf8CStringInts.count
    let data = NSMutableData(length: count)!
    data.resetBytes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: count))

    // Copy into NSMutableData
    let pointer = data.mutableBytes
    var index = 0
    for byte in utf8CStringInts {
        pointer.storeBytes(of: byte, toByteOffset: index, as: UInt8.self)
        index += 1
    }

    return data
}
```

The following will correctly print "UTF-8 Bytes: 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x00":

```
let utf8Data = getUtf8Bytes(of: "123")
let debugString = (utf8Data.copy() as! Data).map { String(format: "0x%02x ", $0) }.joined()
print("UTF-8 Bytes: " + debugString)
```

However, if I take out the copy as follows it will incorrectly print "0x31 0x00 0x00 0x00":

```
let utf8Data = getUtf8Bytes(of: "123")
let debugString = utf8Data.map { String(format: "0x%02x ", $0) }.joined()
print("UTF-8 Bytes: " + debugString)
```

Can someone explain why the results are printed correctly after copying it to a Data?

Comment: This is an interesting question but why are you using `NSMutableData` in Swift at all? `"123".data(using: .utf8)` would do the same, only without the null separator.

Comment: The problem happens only if you don't include `Foundation`. Adding `include Foundation` will probably fix your problem.

Comment: I'm using NSMutableData because the API I'm calling takes the data in using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting... So after some sniffing around, here's what I found.

*Copying* the `NSMutableData` is not the solution, but rather, bridging it to `Data`. This will work as well:

```swift
let utf8Data = getUtf8Bytes(of: "123")
let debugString = (mutableData as Data).map { String(format: "0x%02x ", $0) }.joined()
print("UTF-8 Bytes: \(debugString)")
```

But why? The problem appears to stem from `NSData`'s conformance to `DataProtocol` (& its subsequent implicit inheritance of the `Collection` protocol). It's through this chain of implicit inheritance that permits the (mis)use of these generic `Collection` methods (e.g. subscript access, `map`, `forEach`, etc.) that are all "*broken*".

Furthermore, we can verify the byte contents of the `NSMutableData` are correct:

```swift
print((0..<mutableData.length)
            .map({ String(format: "0x%02x ", mutableData.bytes.load(fromByteOffset: $0, as: UInt8.self)) })
            .joined())
// Prints "0x31 0x32 0x33 0x00"
```

---

Also, there's a swift-ier way to implement `getUtf8Bytes(of:)`:

```swift
public func getUtf8Bytes(of str: String) -> NSMutableData {
    // Note: You may want to handle the force unwrapping here in a safer way...
    return NSMutableData(data: (str + "\0").data(using: .utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: Ah very interesting, thanks!  I need to do more reading about how the Swift to Objective C bridging works.  Also thanks for the more concise implementation.